# Returned malformed array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I'm new with angular and typescript.

I'm having a problem with the return array from a method.
Here is what I did.

I had a global variable:

```
    locations: string[] = [];
```

In ngOnInit(),
I will call this method and push some string inside the array:

```
    this.getAllLocationWithinUserCountry();

    getAllLocationWithinUserCountry() {
      let location = localStorage.getItem('location');    
      location = JSON.parse(location).name;   
    
      this.memberListService.getLocationsFromAPI(location).subscribe((res: any) => {      
        for (let index in res.result) {      
           this.locations.push(res.result[index].location_name);       
        }
      });
    }
```

if I will log the locations, in browsers console I see:

```
    []
      0: "USA"
      1: "Canada"
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

//sorry somehow unable to paste my image. so I just type it.

Somehow I'm unable to pass this array to a new method with array param. See below ex:

```
    getTransactions2(locations: string[]){
         console.log("location val===="+locations);
    }
```

but if I will create a new array like this below:

```
    let newlocation: string[] = ["USA","London"];
```

I can see that it was passed. And this is what I see in browser console if I log this newlocation:

```
    (2)['USA','London']
      0: "USA"
      1: "London"
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

//sorry somehow unable to paste my image. so I just type it.

If I try to loop in this.locations, it seems that I can't either loop in this array.
See ex:

```
    for (let index of this.locations) {
      console.log("===In loop==="); // no logs
      console.log("value==="+index);// no logs
    }
```

Please help me to correct the array or the way I add the string to it.
Not sure how to fix the array and pass it to the method successfully.
TIA.

Comment: When you call `getTransactions2` soon after `this.getAllLocationWithinUserCountry();` call like `getTransactions2(this.locations)` ?

Comment: @NavnathJadhav actually, that is what I did. But it seems that it is not accepted as param in  getTransactions2(locations: string[]). Not sure what is wrong. Unlike when I passed the newlocation, It seems to accept it and able to log.

Comment: It due to network call made by `this.memberListService.getLocationsFromAPI` . im working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your `getTransactions2` gets called before you gets response from your api call `this.memberListService.getLocationsFromAPI(location)` and this.location gets filled.

You need to call `getTransactions2` after your successful api call.

Check out this solution.

```
  locations: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllLocationWithinUserCountry()
      .pipe(tap(this.getTransactions2))
      .subscribe(locationNames => (this.locations = locationNames));
  }

  getAllLocationWithinUserCountry(): Observable<any> {
    const storageData = localStorage.getItem('location');
    const location = storageData ? JSON.parse(storageData).name : [];

    return this.memberListService.getLocationsFromAPI(location).pipe(
      pluck('result'),
      map((resultArray: any[]) => resultArray.map(item => item.location_name))
    );
  }

  getTransactions2(locations: string[]): void {
    console.log('location val====', locations);
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah1i6b?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I tried this and it works! Thank you very much for helping me also I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this execution order:

```
locations: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getAllLocationWithinUserCountry();

    this.getTransactions2(this.locations);

    for (let index of this.locations) {
      console.log("===In loop===");
      console.log("value===" + index);
    }
  }

  getAllLocationWithinUserCountry() {
    let location = localStorage.getItem('location');
    location = JSON.parse(location).name;

    this.memberListService.getLocationsFromAPI(location).subscribe((res: any) => {
      for (let index in res.result) {
        this.locations.push(res.result[index].location_name);
      }
    });

  }

  getTransactions2(locations: string[]) {
    console.log("location val====" + locations);
  }
```

Comment: This is more like what i did. It just that my question above code are incomplete.  I tried this on my end, i get a blank value when i log the this.locations in ngOnInit() . Thanks for trying